# How do I embed a Google Photos album into a web site?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-photos

According to Google's help pages, one can embed pictures from Google Photos onto an external web site:

[image: embed picture instructions]

... but, although it says there's a "Link to this album" on the right hand side, with an "Embed Slideshow", I can't find it anywhere.

[image: album options]

There's nothing about embedding under "Share", or anywhere else.

How do I embed an album of photos uploaded to Google on my web site?

Comment: The answer to this until recently was that it took you back to the Picasa web interface, but that appears to have been disabled.

Comment: You are looking at Google Plus, the text you are referencing is about using Google Picasa.

Comment: @Blyss: Exactly. The two are connected, but not clearly, which confuses the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Proposed by an anonymous user, as a suggested edit to the accepted answer:*

Setting up Albums and generating the code to embed them in a web site is made unnecessarily complicated by Google.  They really should make this more intuitive.  Below are detailed instructions for how I learned (the hard way) to do it.

---

**CREATE A NEW ALBUM IN GOOGLE+ PHOTOS**

In Google, select the icon at the upper right that looks like a tic-tac-toe board (or waffle iron), and select the red Google+ icon (may have to sign in).

- Open the drop list on the upper left that says Home, and select
  Photos.
- Select All Photos from the top.
- To see any existing Albums, select More at the top, and then Albums.
- If no photos are loaded, you will need to load some before you can
  create Albums.
- Go back to All Photos.
- Upload some photos by selecting Upload Photos, and following the
  directions.
- When some photos are uploaded, go back to All Photos to see them.
- Click on an individual photo, and a bigger view of that photo will
  pop up.
- Move the mouse to hover over the big photo, and a circled check mark
  will appear in the upper left corner.
- Click on the circled check mark, and options will appear in a blue
  strip across the top. Select Copy.
- A pop up will appear with the existing Albums, or you can enter the
  name of a new Album to create one.
- When done, hit Copy at the bottom.

---

**EMBED AN ALBUM IN THE WEB SITE (Weebly as an example)**

To create the links in the site requires the set up of Albums first in Google+ Photos (see instructions above for that), and then you have to go to the site called https://picasaweb.google.com to get the embedding code.

- Go to the picasaweb site.
- Any Albums that have been set up should show up under the Home tab.
- Under the thumbnail for each Album are three lines: the Album name, a
  date, and the number of photos.
- Just to the left of the number of photos is a little icon that is
  either a padlock or a roundish gray-and-white icon that is hard to
  describe.
- If it is a padlock, it means that the Album can not be seen with a
  link, and you can't generate embedding code for it, so it must be
  changed.
- To change it for linking, click on the Album, select Actions, and
  select Album Properties.
- In the Edit Album Information pop up, open the Visibility drop list
  at the bottom, and pick Limited, Anyone With The Link, then Save
  Changes at the bottom.
- Then select the Home tab, and make sure the icon under the Album has
  changed.
- If it is the right icon, then click on the Album, and on the right
  side, click on the the blue text that says Link To This Album.
- Then click on the blue text on the lower right that says Embed
  Slideshow.
- A pop up will open, and select the slideshow size that is desired
  (large is the one I pick).
- Then copy the code in the yellow box, and paste that into a Weebly
  Custom HTML code box.
- Hit Done on the pop up.
- It is also a good idea to then copy the link address that is on the
  right under Paste Link In Email or IM, and then paste that in a
  regular Weebly text box.
- After putting it in the text box, you will have to highlight that
  text, and select the option Weebly gives to make it a hot link.
- The reason why it is a good idea to paste this link in along with the
  embedding is that the embedded slideshow may not show up on some
  devices (mostly Apple devices), and the link gives those users an
  alternative way to get to the photos.
- To size the embedded slideshow, edit the code to include height and
  width (e.g. 500 and 700). Then publish the Weebly site, and check
  that it all works.

Comment: Yeah, just seen this "edit" in the review queue! Thanks for posting it as a separate answer (as it should be IMO). (Why didn't the anon-user just post the answer?!)

Comment: I suspect this answer is now out of date since Google appears to have retired https://picasaweb.google.com

Comment: yeah this Answer is outdated, watch out.